# Puppet install package greater than & less than?

Tags: puppet

If I have the following it works fine:

```
package { 
  2klic-certificates>=1.0.3: ensure => installed,
}
```

But `2klic-certificates` is from a custom repository where we also have beta versions. So I'd also like to put an upper limit. I'm trying:

```
package { 
  2klic-certificates>=1.0.3<1.1.0: ensure => installed,
}
```

This returns the error:

```
Error: Execution of '/usr/bin/apt-get -q -y -o DPkg::Options::=--force-confold --force-yes install 2klic-certificates>=1.0.3<1.1.0' returned 100: Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package 2klic-certificates>
Error: /Stage[main]/Main/Node[default]/Package[2klic-certificates>=1.0.3<1.1.0]/ensure: change from purged to present failed: Execution of '/usr/bin/apt-get -q -y -o DPkg::Options::=--force-confold --force-yes install 2klic-certificates>=1.0.3<1.1.0' returned 100: Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package 2klic-certificates>
```

I've also tried:

```
package { 
  2klic-certificates>=1.0.3 and <1.1.0: ensure => installed,
}
```

Looking through the [documentation](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.10/lang_expressions.html) I don't see an option to explicitly specify a minimum and maximum version number. Is this possible?

Comment: No, you cannot do this intrinsically. I have achieved this before with a combo custom fact/custom function/defined type.

Comment: @MattSchuchard interested in hearing more. I can't imagine how a fact would come into play for this use case.

Comment: @MattSchuchard I'm thinking maybe you stored the version of a program as a fact and used different confiig files based on that?

Comment: Check these: https://github.com/mschuchard/snippets-and-notes/blob/master/puppet/puppet-4.3/custom/lib/facter/facter_plugin.rb#L87, https://github.com/mschuchard/snippets-and-notes/blob/master/puppet/puppet-4.3/custom/lib/puppet/parser/functions/rpm_version_comp.rb, https://github.com/mschuchard/snippets-and-notes/blob/master/puppet/puppet-4.3/custom/manifests/special_install.pp#L9

Comment: So what that will actually do is update a package if you specified something newer and do nothing otherwise, but you can adapt it for your needs by changing the code for checking if it is `>=` to also check for `<=`.

Comment: Using the yum provider as an example, this is why you cannot do it intrinsically: https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet/blob/master/lib/puppet/provider/package/yum.rb#L151. Without getting bogged down, your string specified in ensure becomes prefixed with - and assigned to the wanted variable in that line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will leave this open as this answer isn't a full solution, but rather a workaround *(confirmed to work on apt based systems)*.

We had the freedom to control our package naming convention and combined this with wildcards. So for example:

```
package { 
  2klic-certificates>=1.0.*: ensure => latest,
}
```

Will ensure that the latest package in the 1.0 section is installed.

So If a node has version `1.0.1` and `1.0.3` is available and we have a beta version of `1.1.0`, the above will make sure `1.0.3` is installed on our main nodes and ignore the beta version.

As mentioned this is not a real solution as you can't always control the naming convention for versions. It works for my initial question but if you wanted between `1.0.1` and `1.1.5` for example it would essentially be useless.

---

*In which case I would recommend looking at the snippets posted by @MattSchuchard*